# Multiple inheritance in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

How to inherit QLabel and QPushButtton too, what I tried shows error messages

```
/home/test.cpp:206: error: reference to 'setText' is ambiguous
      setText(text);
      ^
```

Here is what I tried:

```
class virtualLabel: virtual public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit virtualLabel(const QString& text="", QWidget* parent=0){}
    ~virtualLabel(){}

};

class virtualPushButton: virtual public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit virtualPushButton(const QString& text="", QWidget* parent=0){}
    ~virtualPushButton(){}

};



class customLabel : public virtualLabel, public virtualPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE
    //Q_INTERFACES(YourInterface OtherInterface)


public:
    explicit customLabel(const QString& text="", QWidget* parent=0);
    ~customLabel();

    QString folderName;

};
```

Any help appreciated  Thank You

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please use only the relevant tag.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It looks like you want a button that is also a label?  If so, don't bother with QLabel at all, just use (or subclass) QPushButton and call setText() on it to set its label.  In general, using multiple inheritance to inherit from more than one QObject-subclass is a bad idea.

Comment: i want to use all the signal&slot of QPushButton and QLabel on a single object @ Jeremy Friesner

Comment: @jeremyfriesner inheritance from multiple QObject subclasses is not just bad idea, it is not supported.

Answer (score 6):

You don't.

Apart from the issue with ambiguity you will have a lot more issues.

From the Qt documentation on [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first):

> Virtual inheritance with QObject is *not* supported.

*(Trust them on that)*

Rather use composition and expose the signals, slots and functions you need.

```
class customLabel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit customLabel(const QString& text="", QWidget* parent=0);
    ~customLabel();
protected:
    QPushButton* button;
    QLabel* label;
};
```

Comment: One reason why this does not work is the conflict in meta-information of the shared QObject, which both the Label and the Button share. The dreaded diamond!

Comment: @jens seems like your comment applied to the question, not to this answer?

Comment: well I need to make entity that will hold the property of both qlable as well as qpushbutton , is there any other way I can do it,

Comment: Note that both sub-widgets can be held by value. No reason to keep them via pointer.

Comment: @Schollii: It was kind of a comment on "Trust them in that". I wanted to give some understanding why the answer is correct and you should never use multiple virtual interheritance on any QObject derived class.

Comment: @jens Good comment but the word "this"  is misleading (sound like it refers to the answer, where in fact it refers to multiple inheritance of QObject), so it would be nice if you replaced your comment to replace "this"  with something clearer.